# Clicking on Multiple buttons with same name,class,text in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

**This is the html from where i want to click multiple buttons name restart**

```
<tbody>
<tr class="el-table__row">
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_2_column_9 el-table__cell">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="oui-network-badge">
                <div class="head" style="background-color: rgb(144, 240, 144);">4g1</div>
                <div>ppp10</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_2_column_10 el-table__cell">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="el-row" style="width: 100%;"><span>311480724822816</span></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_2_column_11 el-table__cell">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="el-row" style="width: 100%;"><span>100.107.30.18</span></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_2_column_12 el-table__cell">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="el-row" style="width: 100%;"><span>174.206.239.56</span></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_2_column_13 el-table__cell">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="el-row" style="width: 100%;"><span>198.224.184.135</span></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_2_column_14 el-table__cell">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="el-row" style="width: 100%;"><span>198.224.185.135</span></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_2_column_15 el-table__cell">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="el-row" style="width: 100%;"><span>807742644 bytes</span></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_2_column_16 el-table__cell">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="el-row" style="width: 100%;"><span>44624791 bytes</span></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_2_column_17 is-hidden el-table__cell">
        <div class="cell">
            <button type="button" class="el-button el-button--default el-button--mini">
                <!----><!---->
                <span>Refresh</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="el-button el-button--warning el-button--mini">
                <!----><!---->
                <span>Redial</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="el-button el-button--danger el-button--mini">
                <!----><!---->
                <span>Restart</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="el-button el-button--primary el-button--mini">
                <!----><!---->
                <span>Edit</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="el-table__row el-table__row--striped">
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_2_column_9 el-table__cell">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="oui-network-badge">
                <div class="head" style="background-color: rgb(144, 240, 144);">4g2</div>
                <div>ppp11</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_2_column_10 el-table__cell">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="el-row" style="width: 100%;"><span>311480724839466</span></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_2_column_11 el-table__cell">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="el-row" style="width: 100%;"><span>100.98.149.115</span></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_2_column_12 el-table__cell">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="el-row" style="width: 100%;"><span>174.206.225.91</span></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_2_column_13 el-table__cell">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="el-row" style="width: 100%;"><span>198.224.184.135</span></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_2_column_14 el-table__cell">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="el-row" style="width: 100%;"><span>198.224.185.135</span></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_2_column_15 el-table__cell">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="el-row" style="width: 100%;"><span>440025553 bytes</span></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_2_column_16 el-table__cell">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="el-row" style="width: 100%;"><span>25038298 bytes</span></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="el-table_2_column_17 is-hidden el-table__cell">
        <div class="cell">
            <button type="button" class="el-button el-button--default el-button--mini">
                <!----><!---->
                <span>Refresh</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="el-button el-button--warning el-button--mini">
                <!----><!---->
                <span>Redial</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="el-button el-button--danger el-button--mini">
                <!----><!---->
                <span>Restart</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="el-button el-button--primary el-button--mini">
                <!----><!---->
                <span>Edit</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<!---->
```

I want to click all restart button one by one or at once ,This is the code i have tried

```
    const newel= await page.$x("//button[contains(text(),'Restart')]");
  if(el){

      await Promise.all([page.waitForNavigation(),  newel[0].evaluate(e=>e.click())]);
    }
```

when I have console the newel it is showing empty,i know the problem cause there are multiple buttons with same text,class and name so how can i specify each so i can click these buttons.

Comment: Is there a particular reason not to use a simple class on the restart buttons and then get them with a querySelector instead of matching textContent ?

Comment: yes cause all button have same class if i am using class then it will return empty cause there  is no specific class for particular element